# Manage , create , edit files like text files,spread sheets,folders

Tags: iphone, xcode4.3

[image]

am newbie and 
I want to try App something similar to the image shown above(Documents free)..How can i create , edit , manage all kinds of files like text files, spread sheet,and other folders , What i have to use and how can i achieve this..please guide me..It will be a great help...
Thanks in advance...

Please give me explanations 1) how can i create that small window which contains 5 icons??
2) How can i create that file icons 
3)When i click on the particular icon it should open the respective editor.
So please help me..

Answer (score 0):

From your question it's look like you gonna need to learn the basics of building app, please make couple of tutorials to understand how you build an app.
I would recommend this tutorials from [raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials)

It'll basically help you answer yourself on questions 1 and 3.
about question 2- it's just images that you can get from the new/ your graphic designer.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for Your guidance yar..but can you please tell me how can i create , edit the text and spread sheet files in the app..